# Start menu and "action center" cannot be opened in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1511

After about 2 months from updrading from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 10 I am having weird issues: When I click Windows icon, nothing happenes - Windows menu is not opened.

The same happens when I press the (Win) key on keyboard - Windows menu is not opened.

Also clicking on sound menu does not do anything - sound control does not appear.

The same with Action Center: Clicking the icon does nothing.

Restart of computer helps, but temporarily: After some time the icons do nothing. Is there something I can check or do in order to fix this?

**Edit:** Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586] is the build of the system

Comment: You should perform a Reset on your installation.  What you describe is caused by corrupt system files, what build of Windows 10, are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]. I did perform reset of computer several times and this problem reoccurs. Can you describe me more of what should I do?

Comment: try looking at Task Manger process list when you don't have the problem and take screenshots of currently running processes. when you have the issue open the task manager again and see if one of the vital windows processes are missing/crashed, and while you're there  look for any suspicious activity/load on memory, cpu or disk. I'm looking arround to see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: also take a look [here](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532) try "Reinstalling Windows apps" it seems to fix this for a lot of people.