# Did I get hacked? Weird chinese files in Win 10 "recent files"

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-explorer

Whenever I open the file browser, I see this in last files:
[image: last files]

All of the above files should be on Desktop, where I do see nothing. I tried to google translate the file names, but no good. I tried to copypaste some filenames here, but seems like the editor does not allow me to do so.

Maybe is worth noticing I am Czech and do not speak Chinese, or use any Chinese pages

Did anyone face such thing? And what should I do?

Edit: Apart from [weird start menu behvior,](https://superuser.com/questions/1032938/start-menu-and-action-center-cannot-be-opened-in-windows-10) my computer behaves normally

Comment: You have not been hacked.  What language packs do you have installed?

Comment: @Ramhound How do I tell? But I would guess that I have Czech and maybe English and thats it

Comment: I cannot "I would guess" statements.  My thought process requires 100% for sure answers from you.  [Use the Windows 10 equivalent of this information.](http://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8)

Comment: see this page...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: @Moab after more tham 4 years using the computer, I was afraid that I need to reinstall... Seems like only viable option at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say you have been hacked, as, well, to be honest your machine would be in a lot worse state than this. I would however download and install some AV software and make sure you scan your machine for malware, trojans and rootkits.

The most likely event is that you downloaded something you shouldn't of and it's installed some sniffing software looking for credit card details etc.

I would also recommend changing all passwords and login details to anything that may of been compromised including online sites. Personally I would do this from another computer unless you are 100% sure there is no malware at all on your system.

I would also check your installed programs and delete any files you don't recognise in your user folders.

There is also a better forum for this question here:
https://security.stackexchange.com/

Some free but good AV resources:

Avira:
http://www.avira.com/en/avira-free-antivirus

Avast:
https://www.avast.com/

Malwarebytes:
https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/

hope this helps, if you need any further help just ping me a message in the comments :)

Comment: I forgot to mention: I have Avast installed and I am running the test now

Comment: Google translate couldn't identify any of the words I copied and pasted except three: `destroy`, `industry` and `despair`.  So ... I'm thinking I have a virus developed by a chinese cult bent on world domination.  Or maybe it's VLC media player.  https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=90318  Eh, either way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Translate the file names via the wonderful web, i.e. google translate, do some web browsing and someone or something may be able to shed some light. Translate only parts of the file name to try and pull something out, they're likely to be a jumble of characters, even the English do it.
2. Possibility of a trojan horse virus or most likely a worm, do a FULL virus scan and delete the files.
3. If these came from some sort of installer, it may be worth doing a system restore.

Note: If the files are stated to be stored on the desktop and aren't visible, then they are there only marked as a hidden file...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause was **VLC media player**:

> Try VLC 1.2 from [Nightly Build of VLC](http://nightlies.videolan.org/)

> Uninstalled 1.1.9 making sure to have it delete preferences and cache.
>
> Downloaded vlc-1.2.0-git-20110321-1826-win32.exe
>
> Seems to have resolved the behavior.

[source](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=90318)

I suspected **VLC** because the chinese files were mixed around and between video files that I had been editing using VLC.  The above *appears* to have resolved the issue for me.

I'm still doing a full virus scan, though.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw the problem with VLC. I was opening an mp3 file.

I saw this file named with Chinese characters under QuickAccess.   Did not know where it came from. I removed it from QuickAccess.

Again when I opened the mp3 file with VLC, the file with the Chinese characters under QuickAccess reappeared.

I may need to upgrade my VLC software.